# @Autowired not wiring my repository - null pointer exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, autowired

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ImportCSV {
                
        @Autowired
        private static PersonRepository personRepository; //does not seem to work
        
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            SpringApplication.run(ImportCSV.class, args);
            Person person = new Person();
            // Add a bunch of setters for person
                personRepository.save(person); //personRepository is null
        }
   }

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>{

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Persons")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    /*Declare relevant fields here*/
}
```

Please see above code. 'personRepository' is null. How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong -- how does Autowire work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does not inject into static fields. So you have to remove the `static` keyword from the personRepository field. The compiler will complain then, that you cannot access a non-static field from a static method. To solve this, implement the `ApplicationRunner` interface, which defines a `run` method. In that method, you can run all the code, that should be run after the Spring Boot application is started, e.g. for initializing any data in the database etc.
That would be the proper Spring Boot way to execute code after the application is started.
For even more cleaner code then, you can create a separate class, that implements the `ApplicationRunner` interface and move the code there.

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ImportCSV implements ApplicationRunner {
            
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository; //does not seem to work
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(ImportCSV.class, args);
    }

    @Override 
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {  
         Person person = new Person();

         personRepository.save(person); 
    }
}
```